# java connection pool autocommit

Tags: java, database, glassfish-3, sqldatasource

I'm using for the first time the connection pool in java. The application that I'm writing is a web application deployed on oracle glassfish 3.1 and the resource connection pool is handled by it. I set the autocommit to false on my connection object, returned by the  javax.sql.DataSource, but in the code the rollback command has no effect at all. All the previous operation of write are committed automatically. Is there any other settings in java code that I have to do to disable autocommit? Or there is some configuration settings that I have to do on glassfish?

The database that I'm using is Oracle 10g.

I post here a part of the code that is giving me problem:

```
private int importFile(String id, String fileName, String label,
        String prosumerId, String districtCodes)
        throws IOException,
        SQLException {

    logger.debug("Importing file [" + fileName + "]");
    File f = new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = null;

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String query = "insert into TB_SDK_USER_FILES values ("
            + id + ", '" + label + "', '"
            + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "', 'active', "
            + "to_date('" + sdf.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis())) + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), "
            + "to_date('" + sdf.format(new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis())) + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), "
            + "'" + prosumerId + "'"
            + ") ";

    logger.debug("Executing query [" + query + "]");

    dbl.openDBConnection();

    int x = dbl.set(query);

    if (x <= 0) {
        dbl.rollback();
        dbl.closeDBConnection();
        logger.error("Insert in TB_SDK_USER_FILES failed, stopping execution ");

        return -3;
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String line = new String();

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));


        query = "insert into TB_SDK_CONTENTS "
                + "(id, contentCode, cli, content, contentType, PROSUMERID, cld, email) "
                + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        logger.debug("Executing query [" + query + "]");
        ps = dbl.getPreparedStatement(query);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tmp = line.split("\t");
            if (tmp.length < 4) {
                logger.debug("Sono presenti erroneamente meno di 4 valori!!!!");
                br.close();
                f.delete();
                dbl.rollback();
                ps.close();
                dbl.closeDBConnection();
                return -2;
            }

            ps.setInt(1, new Integer(id).intValue());

            String test = tmp[0].replace("*", "");
            logger.debug("first column: test [" + test + "]");
            try {
                if (test.length() > 0) {
                    double testDouble = Double.parseDouble(test);
                    //int testInt = Integer.parseInt(test);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                logger.error("The first column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[0] + "] -- NumberFormatException");
                dbl.rollback();
                ps.close();
                dbl.closeDBConnection();
                br.close();
                f.delete();
                return -6;
            }
            if (tmp[0].length() > 0) {
                ps.setString(2, tmp[0].trim());
            } else {
                logger.error("The first column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[0] + "] -- length() <= 0");
                dbl.rollback();
                ps.close();
                dbl.closeDBConnection();
                br.close();
                f.delete();
                return -6;
            }

            test = tmp[1].replace("*", "").trim();
            logger.debug("second column: test [" + test + "]");
            try {
                if (test.length() > 0) {
                    double testDouble = Double.parseDouble(test);
                    //int testInt = Integer.parseInt(test);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                logger.error("The second column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[1] + "]");
                dbl.rollback();
                ps.close();
                dbl.closeDBConnection();
                br.close();
                f.delete();
                return -7;
            }
            if (tmp[1].length() > 0) {
                ps.setString(3, tmp[1].trim());
            } else {
                logger.error("The second column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[1] + "] -- length() <= 0");
                dbl.rollback();
                ps.close();
                dbl.closeDBConnection();
                br.close();
                f.delete();
                return -7;
            }                

            logger.debug("third column: tmp[2] [" + tmp[2] + "]");
            ps.setString(4, tmp[2]);

            if ((tmp[3].length() > 0) && ((tmp[3].compareToIgnoreCase("TTS") == 0)
                    || (tmp[3].compareToIgnoreCase("Audio") == 0))) {
                ps.setString(5, tmp[3].trim());
                logger.debug("fourth column: tmp[3] [" + tmp[3] + "]");
            } else {
                logger.error("The fourth column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[3] + "]");
                dbl.rollback();
                ps.close();
                dbl.closeDBConnection();
                br.close();
                f.delete();
                return -10;
            }

            ps.setString(6, prosumerId);

            if (tmp.length > 4) {
                tmp[4] = tmp[4].trim();

                if ((tmp[4].length() > 0) && (tmp[4].length() <= 12) && (tmp[4].matches("^\\d*$"))) {
                    boolean ok = false;
                    logger.debug("Checking district codes...");
                    String[] codes = districtCodes.split(",");
                    for (int i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
                        if (tmp[4].startsWith(codes[i].trim())) {
                            ok = true;
                            logger.debug("District code found.");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ok) {
                        ps.setString(7, tmp[4]);
                        logger.debug("fifth column: tmp[4] [" + tmp[4] + "]");
                    } else {
                        logger.error("The fifth column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[4] + "]");
                        dbl.rollback();
                        ps.close();
                        dbl.closeDBConnection();
                        br.close();
                        f.delete();
                        return -8;
                    }
                } else if (tmp[4].length() == 0) {
                    ps.setString(7, "-");
                    logger.debug("fifth column: tmp[4] [-]");
                } else {
                    logger.error("The fifth column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[4] + "]");
                    dbl.rollback();
                    ps.close();
                    dbl.closeDBConnection();
                    br.close();
                    f.delete();
                    return -8;
                }
            } else {
                ps.setString(7, "-");
            }

            if (tmp.length == 6) {
                tmp[5] = tmp[5].trim();
                if ((tmp[5].length() > 0) && (isValidEmailAddress(tmp[5]))) {
                    ps.setString(8, tmp[5]);
                } else if (tmp[5].length() == 0) {
                    ps.setString(8, "-");
                } else {
                    logger.error("The sixth column does not satisfy the format requested. Found [" + tmp[5] + "]");
                    dbl.rollback();
                    ps.close();
                    dbl.closeDBConnection();
                    br.close();
                    f.delete();
                    return -9;
                }
            } else {
                ps.setString(8, "-");
            }


            x = ps.executeUpdate();

            if (x <= 0) {
                dbl.rollback();
                ps.close();
                dbl.closeDBConnection();
                br.close();
                //f.delete();
                logger.error("Insert in TB_SDK_CONTENTS failed, stopping execution ");

                return -3;
            }

        }

        br.close();
        //f.delete();
        ps.close();
        dbl.commit();
        dbl.closeDBConnection();
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("An exception occured during the import of file [" + fileName + "] for line [" + line + "]", ex);
        dbl.rollback();
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
        dbl.closeDBConnection();
        //f.delete();
        return -1;
    }

}
```

On the other class that handle the DB operation:

```
public int set(String query) {
    Statement statement = null;
    int ris = -1;

    try {
        if (connection == null || !connection.isValid(1)) connect();
        logger.debug("Opening statement");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ris = statement.executeUpdate(query);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        logger.error("ERROR in execution of [" + query + "] due to: ", ex);
        ris = -1;
    } finally {
        try {
            logger.debug("Closing statement");
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex1) {
            logger.error("ERROR cannot close statement.", ex1);
        }
    }
    return ris;

}
```

The connection open:

```
public boolean connect() {

    if (dataSource != null) {
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            logger.info("Connection open to DB");
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error("An error occured during request of connection to datasource, due to...", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    String url;
    if (connectionString.length() > 0) {
        url = connectionString;
    } else {
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + port + ":" + sid;
    }

    try {

        // create an OracleDataSource
        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        // set connection properties
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("user", user);
        prop.put("password", pwd);
        ods.setConnectionProperties(prop);
        ods.setURL(url);

        // get the connection
        connection = ods.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ((OracleConnection) connection).setDefaultRowPrefetch(10);

        logger.info("Connection open to DB");

        return true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.info("An exception occured in execution of [connect]. ");
        if (dataSource == null) {
        logger.error("[" + url + ", " + user + ", " + pwd + "] ERROR in execution of [connect] due to: ", ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

dataSource getConnection():

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(false);

    return con;
}
```

The lookup for the data source is done in the Context Listener at context creation.

**Edit:**
I'm reading again the oracle tutorials about the usage of pooling connection and other links about it: every example the open and close of the connection to the pool is done in the same method. I thought that was just a need to be more simplest to explain all the steps, but I'm wondering if this is not also a need to satisfy the "transaction" at connection pool level. Can anyone confirm me this? Or give me a documentation link where this is well explained? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide your code here. It may be something to do with transaction boundaries

Comment: What database are you using? Does it support transactions?

Comment: Are you by any chance using MySQL with MyISAM tables?

Comment: Unfortunately I must use only oracle :(